# Double for loop with if condition

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I am having trouble with double for loop in java, specifically inner if condition

Here is my code:

```
 public Set<Term> getAllTermsForStudent(Long id) {

        List<Term> terms = termRepository.findAll();
        Set<Term> set_terms = new HashSet<Term>(terms); //there are 3 terms
        Set<Exam> exams = studentService.getStudentExams(id); //in this student's case, there are 9 exams, 3 in each term
        Set<Exam> new_exams = new HashSet<>();

        for(Term t: set_terms) { 
            for(Exam e: exams) {
                if(t.getId() == e.getTerm().getId()) { //exam has term id, which indicates to which
                                                         term it belongs, so I'm comparing it, and I 
                                                         want to add it to new exam set
                    new_exams.add(e);
                }
            }
           t.setExams(new_exams);

        }

        return set_terms;
    }
```

Output of this function gives me 9 exams in each term, like it's ignoring if condition

Comment: What type does `Term.id` have? Is it `Long` or `long`?

Comment: @caco3 It is Long, every id in my app has Long

Comment: @MarkoLazarevic try `t.getId().equals(e.getTerm().getId())`. "every id in my app has Long" Does it need to be `Long` (does it ever need to be `null`), or could it be `long` instead?

Comment: @AndyTurner tried it, same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Output of this function gives me 9 exams in each term, like it's ignoring if condition

That's because you're reusing the same `Set` to add exams to.

Declare the variable inside the loop.

```
for(Term t: set_terms) { 
  Set<Exam> new_exams = new HashSet<>();

  for(Exam e: exams) {
    // ...
  }

  t.setExams(new_exams);
}
```